# Rails 3.1 make folder to be public

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Hello I'm new to rails.

In my RoR app folder I have a folder (`app/FOLDER`) that I want to make public (there are script files that need to avaliable from browser), how can I do this?

Comment: you should mark the other answer as accepted, since that's the answer for you (3.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you shouldn't put them in `app/FOLDER`but in `public/FOLDER`, everything going in `public/` is  public.

Here's an explaination of all the directories in a rails app : [guides.rubyonrails.org](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-the-blog-application)

Comment: Thank you, i'm using 3.1 it does not use public for sharing assets any more

Answer (score 5):

In the latest Rails the files should exist in one of the following...

```
app/assets
lib/assets
vendor/assets
```

If you cannot move the folder but still need it to be accessible you can use...

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << folder_path
```

Slightly more detailed answer over here...

[Rails 3.1: The public directory no longer serves js assets. How to load an additional js file after page is loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138041/rails-3-1-the-public-directory-no-longer-serves-js-assets-how-to-load-an-additi/6161406#6161406)